# Creating multiple separate instances of a dataclass with the same arguments

Tags: python, python-3.7, python-dataclasses

I have a simple Python class that looks something like this:

```
class RegularVariable:
    def __init__(self, num_states):
        self.num_states = num_states
```

I recently found out about the `dataclasses` module and replaced my simple class with a dataclass as below:

```
@dataclass(frozen=True)
class DataClassVariable:
    num_states: int
```

(`frozen=True` is set because I do actually intend the class to be read-only.)

Now, at some point in my code, I need to create a bunch of instances of this class with the exact same `num_states`. I can do this easily with the old, simple `RegularVariable` class:

```
print(len(set([RegularVariable(1) for _ in range(10)])))
# prints 10 as expected
```

However, when I try the same thing with my `dataclass` version:

```
print(len(set([DataClassVariable(1) for _ in range(10)])))
# prints 1
```

Why does the `dataclass` behave like this? And given this, how can I create 10 different objects (instantiations) of my `DataClassVariable`?

Comment: I heard that dataclasses do not implement any unique hash by default so if you don't implement a way to differentiate each instance as you use the same value for all of them, `set` might actually think it's all the same instance, maybe. Correct me if I'm wrong, and I'll delete this ;-)

Comment: Every instance of `DataClassVariable` has the same hash (based, I think, only on the value of its `num_states` attribute), so your set really does have only one instance of `DataClassVariable` in it.

Comment: @DevLounge: If you specify `frozen=True`, dataclasses *do* implement `__hash__` and `__eq__` by default. That's *why* this is happening - otherwise, you'd get `10`.

Comment: Ok, so I wasn't too far from the truth but not right neither ;-)

Comment: The combination of properties you want seems a little weird. You want immutable objects, but implementing equality by identity, and you want to use a `set` to store these objects? There are use cases where that can be reasonable, but it's kind of a strange combination. Usually, if identity matters, it's because objects have mutable state, and usually, if you're using sets, you'd want to be able to look up `Thing(1)` in the set and find a match if there's an existing `Thing(1)` there.

Comment: It seems odd that there is no option to simply say "don't override the inherited `__hash__` function".

Comment: Upvoted question as it's been really informative, thanks for asking it!

Comment: Though revisiting the premise, what makes the instances distinct if they are just read-only wrappers around an immutable value?

Comment: I bet that's why they've implemented it like this.

Comment: @chepner: There is no option to do that because generating `__eq__` without generating `__hash__` or setting `__hash__` to `None` would result in `__hash__` and `__eq__` being inconsistent with each other. This is almost always wrong, and is not something worth providing dedicated support for. If you write your own `__hash__`, you can make it inconsistent with `__eq__` yourself, but they're not going to put in a "please make `__hash__` and `__eq__` inconsistent for me" option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the comments, the solution is to add `eq=False`

```
@dataclass(frozen=True, eq=False)
class DataClassVariable:
    num_states: int
```

Comment: Thanks for this! I looked over the documentation earlier, but now that I reread it, it clearly mentions "This method compares the class as if it were a tuple of its fields, in order", which is the behavior I want to disable. While this works for my needs, I realize from @chepner's answer that this has additional consequences that are undesirable...

Comment: No issue, I might end up deleting this answer, as his is much safer indeed. However the option exists and migh be good for some people requirements, so not sure what to do.

Comment: I think it's informative, so I'd leave it; it's useful to know imo.

Comment: Fair enough so I will leave it.

Comment: Yeah, I'd leave it as well (though maybe emphasize that `__hash__` not being generated is a consequence of `__eq__` not being generated either).

Comment: @njk23: `eq=False` disables exactly the behavior you want to disable. chepner's answer keeps it, and has the additional negative consequence of making `__hash__` and `__eq__` inconsistent.

Answer (score 0):

When `frozen=True`, `dataclass` will attempt to generate a `__hash__` function, and will do so based only on the value of `num_states`.

You can explicitly define `__hash__` to be something like

```
@dataclass(frozen=True)
class DataClassVariable:
    num_states: int
    def __hash__(self):
        return super().__hash__()
```

to prevent the autogenerated function from making each instance look identical. Note that this doesn't require disabling the autogeneration of `__eq__`.

Comment: Oh, so is my solution wrong? If yes, sorry

Comment: Not really wrong; it just has additional consequences. I thought there was a way to specifically avoid generating `__hash__`, allowing `object.__hash__` to be inherited, but there doesn't seem to be a way.

Comment: yeah, I tried If `unsafe_hash=True` first but still 1 instead of 10, so I tried `eq=False` instead

Comment: `unsafe_hash` apparently forces `dataclass` to generate `__hash__`, even if `dataclass` determined that it wasn't safe to do so. I also tried `num_states: int = fields(hash=False)`, but then `__hash__` is still generated, rather than just letting `__hash__` be inherited.

Comment: This makes `__eq__` and `__hash__` inconsistent with each other.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out @user2357112 supports Monica; indeed, upon reading the documentation more carefully, it looks like `eq=False` does exactly what I want without this unintended negative consequence. To quote the docs: "If eq is false, __hash__() will be left untouched meaning the __hash__() method of the superclass will be used (if the superclass is object, this means it will fall back to id-based hashing)."